How to check which models tensorflow serving located in the docker container is capable of serving?
I want to use newer model in the tensorflow serving docker container (tensorflow/serving:latest image). Last time this container was initialized more than 2 years ago. So tensorflow serving might be a bit old.
I don't have direct connection to this container, but I'm planning to swap the old model for the newer one (I have access to servable models). How to check which models tensorflow serving is capable of serving? If I do need access to the container in any way, what do I check in there?
